# AS3 rendering bitmaps in GPU mode

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, gpu

Flash Pro CC, AS3, Air for Android (v17), rendering mode GPU, stage quality.LOW, FPS: 60, testing device: an old Nexus One smartphone (Android 2.3.3).

The guides say that GPU makes rendering the bitmaps cheap, somehow i can't grasp how exactly it works.

So i have 49 separate bitmap squares covering the stage and one MovieClip in the middle with a bitmap inside tweened to move up and down (jumping ball). Pretty simple, right?

This is the view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKcJ6.png

1. All graphics are bitmaps (not vectors). Yet i get 55 fps (it varies arround 53-57).
2. Then i select all 49 squares and put them inside a symbol (MovieClip). Visually nothing changes. It seems to increase the FPS a tiny bit, the average fps is now ~57 (55-59).
3. Then i take the MovieClip (with all the squares inside it) and set cacheAsBitmap=true. Voila, now i have 60 fps!

What is happening in all 3 different cases? Why i need to put bitmaps into one MC and cache this MC as bitmap - aren't the squares already bitmaps?

I have also tried to make each square a MovieClip and cache it as bitmap, but i still got 55 fps.

Is it possible to keep squares separate at 60 fps?

In my real project i have many MovieClips on the stage (~100) but in most cases only one of them is animated at a time. Yet somehow it seems that the mere presence of other movieclips reduce the performance (fps). Obviously, i cannot put them all into one MC and cache it as bitmap as in the simplified example above.

How can i solve this, what should i do?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need 60 fps for a Color Lines game? :)

Comment: Good catch ;) Why not 60 fps? Looks much better than 30 fps. And i know 60 fps should be possible even with more animations than i have. Just need to find a way to optimize it.

Comment: Animations look good at 30 fps already, to have a visual difference at 60 fps you need at least 60 pixel distance that ball must go vertically, so each frame it will move at least 1 pixel. Also at 60 fps the battery will drain faster so when designing a game for mobile device you should also care about battery life. Considering the performance, try blitting all movieclips into single bitmap. (Not caching as bitmap but blitting each of them into real bitmap)

Comment: I agree that sometimes slow animations don't need more than 30 fps, but in my case i can see with my own eyes that 60 fps look way smoother and i feel it should be possible to achieve without draining battery much, because, as i mentioned, my animations are simple and there are very few objects being animated at the same time.

Comment: It's not because of the animation. A Flash project has a default frame rate as its property and it will try to run at that frame rate no matter what and how many animations you use. This is what Adobe says: "An application’s frame rate determines how much time is available for each “application code and rendering” cycle, as described in Runtime code execution fundamentals. [...] A higher frame rate expends more CPU cycles and energy from the battery than a lower rate." More here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a61c0b0b612763986266-8000.html

Comment: 15 fps would drain even less, doesn't mean everyone should do 15 fps. Modern games with animations are 60 fps, thats what i aim for too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it relates to this [best practice recommendation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS901d38e593cd1bac-3d719af412b2b394529-8000.html):

> Limit the numbers of items visible on stage. Each item takes some time
>   to render and composite with the other items around it. When you no
>   longer want to display a display object, set its visible property to
>   false. Do not simply move it off stage, hide it behind another object,
>   or set its alpha property to 0. If the display object is no longer
>   needed at all, remove it from the stage with removeChild().

By putting all the bitmaps in a single container and setting `cacheAsBitmap=true` you are essentially turning them into a single bitmap as far as the compositor is concerned. This tends to be faster to composite than multiple individual bitmaps. Setting a bitmap to `cacheAsBitmap=true` (or in a single container with `cacheAsBitmap=true`) has no effect because it's already a bitmap.

Also note that GPU mode isn't recommended anymore, it was Adobe's first attempt at GPU accelerating the display and they basically gave up on that path in favor of the new `Stage3D` rendering pipeline. While GPU render mode can work really well when used just right, it can be somewhat unpredictable and confusing, so I would highly recommend you check out Stage3D.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Stage3D has its downsides too (texture uploading time, memory limit causing crash, texture quality, filters and masking tricky and expensive  to achieve at best, etc ...). GPU mode works fine as long as it fits the type of app you are making, if performance is critical and tons of object have to be on screen Stage3D might be the only viable solution, if it's not the case then GPU mode on mobile is a great solution. (I published many apps on Apply/google store using only GPU mode)

Comment: BotMaster, could you elaborate please? What types of apps GPU mode is best for? I now have an idea to put everything to a cachedAsBitmap container and when i need to animate something inside it, i move it from container to above the container and animate, when animation is done, i put it back to cached container.

Comment: Well, here's some tips on GPU mode: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS5d37564e2b3bb78e5247b9e212ea639b4d7-8000.html

Comment: I achieved 60 fps in GPU mode (even on my old Nexus One) by placing every bitmap into one container and caching that container as bitmap. When i need some MC animated, i take it out of container, place it above the container and run animation. When animation is over, i put it back. This way there are only few separate MCs on a stage and animations are not slowed down. This wouldn't work if i needed more than a few animated MC's at same time.